# Shopify - Redirecting user after Activate Account form is submitted

Tags: shopify

By default, when users Activate their account in a Shopify store, they are redirected to their account page. I'd like to change the destination of that redirect to another page in the Shopify store. I've successfully done this for the Customer Login page to prevent redirection to the account page using a hidden input field for checkout_url, as described in this Shopify support post: http://support.shopify.com/customer/portal/articles/313065-is-it-possible-to-be-redirected-to-a-special-page-upon-being-logged-in-successfully-

However, this approach is not working on the Activate Account form page. Has anyone successfully done this? At least one other Shopify user has encountered this problem as well. http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion/t/account-activation-form-redirect-105959#comment-113150

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing but this isn't working for me? Can I see you full form code to compare?

Answer (score 7):

The good folks at Shopify got back to me about this one. Apparently the following needs to be added to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="**destination**" />
```

Comment: Thanks @erchen ! I´ve been looking around all over for it. Just in case anybody also wants to redirect customers after logged in the code to add is: <input type="hidden" name="checkout_url" value="/pages/special-page" />

Comment: Just for historical purposes, I wanted to mention that this is still the correct answer. Including the `return_to` hidden input in the `{% form 'activate_customer_password' %}` form works. (Oddly, it doesn't work for the regular login form, I have to use `checkout_url` hidden input.)

Comment: This is a super old thread, but as of 2/1/2019 this still works. Huzzah!

Comment: 7/7/2023 still works :D

Answer (score 0):

In the end I gave up trying to use the

`<input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="**destination**" />`

I solved it by adding this script to my /account/ template page

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $(function() {
 if (window.location.href != "http://[yourshopname].com/account") {
 document.location = 'http://[yourshopname].com/'
 }
 }); 
 }); 

 </script>
```